# Facebook App invite requires canvas URL

Tags: ios, facebook

I have the following code to invite people to get this app

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                           message:FACEBOOK_BODY
                                             title:@"Join "
                                        parameters:params
                                           handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                               if (error) {
                                                   // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                   NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                               } else {
                                                   if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                       // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                       NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                   } else {
                                                       NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                   }
                                               }}];
```

This is based off the Facebook samples and only worked once I put in a canvas URL in?

Is this required?  What I want it to do is go to the iTunes url (not populated yet)
I know very little about what the canvas should be.

What I have noticed is that the notification appears on the web app but not under the iOS facebook app making me think this is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by just filling in the canvas URL, even if invalid, things started to work